# Accessing fxml controller's method from fxml loader

Tags: java, javafx, scene

What I want to do is if the size of the scene (the window of the application) is resized, I want to resize the contents inside the window accordingly. I have posted my code which I have done till now

The loader class

```
public class ResizingButtons extends Application {

@Override

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            try{
            System.out.println("Scene Width Property is " + scene.getWidth());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error in width listener of scene" +e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });   
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

And this is the controller of the FXMLDocument.fxml fxml class

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
public Button btn1;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    

public void changeBtnSize(){
    btn1.setPrefHeight(200);
    btn1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
  }
}
```

When the size of the window is resized, I want to access changeBtnSize() method of the controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get controller instance from `FXMLLoader`. Refactor your code like so:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml")); // Use loader instance
    Parent root = loader.load();
    FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController(); // Now you have controller refference here
    //add your listener, feel free to use your controller inside listener implementation
}
```

Comment: Now I am facing problem whenever I try to make changes in the fxml components, from changeListener() method of the loader class, it gives null

`code` scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                try
                {
                controller.resizeComponents();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
`code`

Comment: when I tried to call a method of controller, from the change listener of loader class, it executes print statements but gives a null if I tried to make any changes in the components of fxml

scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,     Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
    try{
    controller.resizeComponents(); //controller is fxmlcontroller's object
    }

//code in controller
    public void resizeComponents(){
    System.out.println("hi");
    acPane.setMinSize(300, 400);
    }

Comment: @viper "gives a null" - what doest it mean? controller instance is null? Do you get `NullPointerException`? "if I tried to make any changes in the components" - What are you tring to do? How are you changing components?

Comment: It just gives a 'null' word in the catch block. Changes means changes in the size of butons and panels

Comment: @viper have you tried to debug your code? Stop execution inside try block and check whether `controller` is not null? Or stop in catch block and check the type of receiving exception?